# For which values of $c \in \mathbb{R}$ the set is precompact in $l_3$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I want to find values that the set $A = \{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_3 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^c \vert x_n \vert^4 \le 1 \}$ is precompact. $l_p$ spaces are precompact if they are bounded and $$\forall \epsilon > 0  \quad \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: (\sum\limits_{i=N}^\infty |x_{i}^{p}|)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \epsilon \quad\forall x \in A$$. I want to use it in a way to solve this question. However, I did not have much progress.

Comment: You want it for arbitrary $p$, or $p = 3$?

Comment: arbitrary p would also be great but I was asking for p=3

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* the main idea is to consider the tail of the series:

$$
\sum_{i \ge N} |x_i|^p = \sum_{i \ge N} \dfrac{1}{n^c} n^c |x_i|^p \le \sum_{i \ge N} \dfrac{1}{n^c} \cdot \sum_{i \ge N} n^c |x_i|^p
$$

Note this is not the tightest bound.

Comment: what implies the inequality here?

Comment: @Treks you need this bound be less than $\varepsilon$. Hence, both of the tails should be low.